# Why does the Java3D canvas flicker when I call Canvas3D.repaint()

Tags: java, java-3d

I have 2D elements I draw with postRender() on a Java3D canvas and want to animate these elements. In a loop I call Canvas3D.repaint():

```
while(animationIsRunning){
    // I update positions of 2D elements here...
    // ...
    canvas3D.repaint();
    Thread.sleep((long)(1.0/30.0 * 1000));
}
```

For every short animation, this causes the whole 3D canvas to flicker once or twice.

Comment: Did you enable double buffering?

Comment: Yes it is enabled, did not help.

Comment: The documentation says that using `postRender()` is not to be done. That might be the problem here.

Comment: A wild guess from some experience here: Try adding `System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true ");` as the **first** line of your `main` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution in my case:

Instead of

```
canvas3d.repaint();
```

I invoke

```
canvas3d.getView().repaint();
```

This way I can update my animation with high framerate without flickering.